# self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview: doesn't load subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ad-hoc-distribution

I have a UITableView with custom cells in it. Each cell has 4 UILabels and 3 UIImageViews, all with user interaction disable.

At didSelectRowAtIndexPath, another view controller (with transparent background) is loaded and animated added to the root view. Simulating a pop up:

```
UIView *rootView = UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController.view;
[rootView addSubview:view];
```

When the app is first installed in the device (built for debug or release), the subview is not seen when a UITableViewCell is selected, it just appears after the cell receives a long press (~ 15 seconds) and crashes. If I open again it works well, or without the long press, if I just build it again it works as expected too.

Here are the methods:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Cell is selected");

    self.popUpViewController = [[PopupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopupViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.popUpViewController.message = [self.arrayOfMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self presentTransparentModalViewController:self.popUpViewController animated:YES withAlpha:1];
}
```

You can check the called method below:

```
-(void) presentTransparentModalViewController: (PopupViewController *) aViewController
                                     animated: (BOOL) isAnimated
                                    withAlpha: (CGFloat) anAlpha{

    self.popUpViewController = aViewController;
    UIView *rootView = UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController.view;

    UIView *view = aViewController.view;
    view.opaque = NO;
    view.alpha = anAlpha;
    [view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        UIView *each = obj;
        each.opaque = NO;
        each.alpha = anAlpha;
    }];
    if (isAnimated) {

        //Animated

        CGRect mainrect = rootView.bounds;
        /* In case you want to add to self.view, use the following instead of the line
           above:
             CGRect mainrect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        */

        CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, mainrect.size.height, mainrect.size.width, mainrect.size.height);

        [rootView addSubview:view];
        /* In case you want to add to self.view, use the following instead of the line
           above:
             [self.view addSubview:view];
        */

        view.frame = newRect;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                         animations:^{
                             view.frame = mainrect;
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             //
                         }];
    }else{
        view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        [rootView addSubview:view];
    }
}
```

**DETAIL:** If the view is added as subview of self.view it works as expected. Why it doesn't work for rootViewController.view?

Does anyone knows why it happens and / or how to fix it?

**EDIT**:
I checked to see if the view is added to rootView.
So, I have rootViewController.view add a subview with transparent background to it.
**What should happens:** We should see the subview, right?
**What actually happens:** We don't see any visual change.
**How do I know the view is there:** If I create an empty view and add my rootView to it, it's shown there.

It happens only after installation, in the first build.

Best regards,
Arthur A.

Comment: Its virtually impossible that the cause is Ad Hoc, per se. More likely is that your testing using Debug, but building the Ad Hoc using Release. Try testing by directly running the app using Release. First, wipe your Derived folder, shut down Xcode, delete the app from your phone, then launch Xcode, insure the developer build is using Release, and load on your app. Also make sure you test the app when your phone is not connected to Xcode. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, David! It was something I did not check. I was able to see the problem. I have a subview added to the rootView. However it doesn't show nothing until I make a - really - long press anywhere on the screen (~ 15 seconds).
However I noticed this behavior on both Debug and Release, only when the app is installed from the first time. If I build again without removing the app it works.

If I add the subview on self.view it works as well, but I really need it to be added to the rootViewController.view, to override the navigationBar.

Did you faced something like that before?

Comment: All I can think of is that there is a race condition in how you are doing this. Everything should be done on the main thread, and also at appropriate times (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, etc). Other than bizarre things happening when you interact with the UI from background threads, no other relative comments.

Comment: Thank you for your time, David! Just for test, even doing it in viewDidLoad doesn't show the subview.

Comment: Add gobs of NSLogs and asserts() - the former to show what the view array looks like at all times - you can dispatch_after to set up a series of logs too. Then add asserts everywhere you are sure your view should be in the array - when you hit the assert (and you need a break point set on exceptions), you can try to reason it out. Timing on first launch may be slightly different than subsequent ones - this is an Apple internals issue no one really would know.

Comment: I checked before, also made a "visual" verification by adding the rootViewController.view as destination subview.

So, I have rootViewController.view add a subview with transparent background to it.
**What should happens:** We should see the subview, right?
**What actually happens:** We don't see any visual change.
**How do I know the view is there:** If I create an empty view and add my rootView to it, it's shown there.

It happens only after installation, in the first build.